# Not able to mock a function inside a test using Jest using Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a file index.ts which has below two functions in it.

index.ts-

```
import { parseExpression } from 'cron-parser';

const previousMillisecondTimestamp = (cron: string, endTime: number): number => {
  try {
    return parseExpression(cron, {
      endDate: new Date(endTime),
      currentDate: new Date(endTime),
      utc: true
    }).prev().getTime()
  } catch(e) {
    return 0;
  }
}


const setNextRun = (nextRunTimestampMilliseconds: number, startTimestampMilliseconds: number = new Date().getTime()) => (x: JobScheduleDto): JobScheduleDto[] => {

  const scheduleIterator = parseExpression(x.cron, {
    /* Line1 */
    startDate: new Date(x.last_run > 900 ? x.last_run - 900 : startTimestampMilliseconds),
    utc: true
  });
  let schedule = scheduleIterator.next();

  let jobQueue: JobScheduleDto[] = [
    {
      ...x,
      next_run: x.next_run ? x.next_run : startTimestampMilliseconds
    }
  ];

  for (; schedule.getTime() < nextRunTimestampMilliseconds ; schedule = scheduleIterator.next()) {
    if(x.next_run === schedule.getTime() || (!x.next_run && startTimestampMilliseconds === schedule.getTime())) {
      continue;
    }
    jobQueue = [...jobQueue, {
      ...x,
      last_run: previousMillisecondTimestamp(x.cron, schedule.getTime()),
      next_run: schedule.getTime()
    }];
  }
  console.log('Values', previousMillisecondTimestamp);
  /* Line2 */
  const updatedLastRun = previousMillisecondTimestamp(x.cron, schedule.getTime()) || schedule.getTime() || x.last_run;
  jobQueue = [...jobQueue, {
    ...x,
    last_run: updatedLastRun,
    next_run: schedule.getTime()
  }];

  return jobQueue;
}

export const testModules = {
  setNextRun,
  previousMillisecondTimestamp,
}
```

Both the functions are exported in an object named as testModules (Required only for testing).
Now in order to increase the branch test coverage, I have to cover lines **Line1** and **Line2** (Commented in above file).

In order to do so in my index.spec.ts file, I want to mock functions *previousMillisecondTimestamp*  and *parseExpression*(External module cron-parser) in my setNextRun function calls. So I can return the output accordingly (undefined or null) in order to cover all branches.

index.spec.ts-

```
import { testModules } from "../../src/index";
import { parseExpression } from 'cron-parser';

const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
const nextRunIntervalInMilliseconds = 10 * 60 * 1000;

  describe.only('setNextRun function test coverage Test', () => {

    it('setNextRun without parameters nextRunTimestampMilliseconds and startTimestampMilliseconds as null and JobScheduleDto object', () => {
      const mockedPreviousMillisecondTimestamp = jest.spyOn(testModules, 'previousMillisecondTimestamp').mockImplementationOnce(() => null);
      console.log('mockedPreviousMillisecondTimestamp', mockedPreviousMillisecondTimestamp);
      const params = { pk: "T5", sk: workdayJobSchedule, last_run: 0, next_run: 0, status: 1, cron: "0 0 4 4 * *", schedule_description: "Desc1" }
      try {
        testModules.setNextRun(currentTime + nextRunIntervalInMilliseconds)(params);
      } catch(error) {
        expect(error.message).toBe("Cannot read property 'cron' of undefined");
      }
      mockedPreviousMillisecondTimestamp.mockRestore();
    });

  });
```

So in the above file when I writing below the line I want to mock the functionality for previousMillisecondTimestamp function and to return null.

```
  const mockedPreviousMillisecondTimestamp = jest.spyOn(testModules, 'previousMillisecondTimestamp').mockImplementationOnce(() => null);
```

Just below that, I am doing a console.log of function to check if the function has been mocked or not and in that console, I am getting that it is mocked which is fine.

[image]

But when it goes inside setNextRun call and there I have a console which gives it as a Normal function.

```
console.log('Values', previousMillisecondTimestamp);
```

[image]

**So I have 2 questions -**

1. What is the right way to mock previousMillisecondTimestamp function in my index.spec.ts file?
2. How I can mock parseExpression function from cron-parser third-party module?

Comment: I think you want something like `jest.mock('cron-parser', {parseExpression: mockParseExpression})` that should replace the dependency in your module graph for the scope of the test

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't work. Mock function is not getting called and original function is getting called.